# MySQL Performance - "IN" Clause vs. Equals (=) for a Single Value

Tags: php, mysql, performance

This is a pretty simple question and I'm assuming the answer is "It doesn't matter" but I have to ask anyway...

I have a generic sql statement built in PHP:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` IN(' . implode(', ', $object_ids) . ')';
```

Assuming prior validity checks (`$object_ids` is an array with at least 1 item and all numeric values), should I do the following instead?

```
if(count($object_ids) == 1) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ' . array_shift($object_ids);
} else {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` IN(' . implode(', ', $object_ids) . ')';
}
```

Or is the overhead of checking `count($object_ids)` not worth what would be saved in the actual sql statement (if any at all)?

Comment: You answered your question :) it doesn't matter. It's also easier to use `implode` without checking the size of the array.

Comment: @N.B. Did anyone ever tell you your name is perfect for comments :P

Comment: @mellamokb - now someone did :)

Comment: @N.B. I figured that was gonna be the case

Comment: SELECT * FROM users u
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 1 as id UNION SELECT 11 as id UNION SELECT 21 as id ) t2
    ON u.id = t2.id

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Neither of them really matter in the big scope of things.  The network latency in communicating with the database will far outweigh either the `count($object_ids)` overhead or the `=` vs `IN` overhead.  I would call this a case of premature optimization.

You should profile and load-test your application to learn where the real bottlenecks are.

Comment: This did not really answer the question!!

Answer (score 79):

Most of the other answers don't provide anything conclusive, just speculation. So, based on the [good advice from @Namphibian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9926626/1924128), I ran an `EXPLAIN` on some queries similar to the ones in the OP.

The results are below:

---

`EXPLAIN` for a query with `= 1`:

[image: Explain for a query with <code>= 1</code>]

---

`EXPLAIN` for a query with `IN(1)`:

[image: Explain for a query with <code>IN(1)</code>]

---

`EXPLAIN` for a query with `IN(1,2,3)`:

[image: Explain for a query with <code>IN(1,2,3)</code>]

---

As you can see, MySQL does optimize `IN(1)` to be the same as `= 1` in this sort of query. [@mes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26275239/1924128) seems to indicate that this might not always be the case with more complex queries, however.

So, for those who were too lazy to run the `EXPLAIN` themselves, now you know. And yes, you may want to run the `EXPLAIN` on your own query to be sure that it is handled this way. :-)

Answer (score 29):

There is no difference between the MySQL statements, and the MySQL optimiser will transform the IN to the = when IN is just one element. Don't bother.

Comment: Could you bring up some MySQL official information to confirm your assertion? Are you completely sure that MySQL optimizer transform it as you explained?

Comment: It's not true, I run query with explain statement and posted screenshots as an answer

Answer (score 9):

Run the two queries with a explain statement. This will show you what MySQL is doing. You focus on MySQL optimisation should be on what is MySQL doing with the query internally. Trying to optimise which query gets executed is a bit premature.

Both these queries could be terrible in performance if there is no index for example. MySQL's EXPLAIN statement is gold here. So when you get to a query that is running slow the EXPLAIN statement will show you why.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that internally mysql will treat the `IN (6)` query exactly as a `= 6` query so there is no need to bother (this is called premature optimization by the way)

Answer (score 2):

I run query with explain statement and here are the results
[image]

It's obvious that "Equals" operator is better, it scans 13 row, and "IN" scans all rows

Comment: Your query has a subquery so it's not necessarily an indication of the optimization of `IN` with one item