# mysql where number in set

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to build a select statement that checks if a number is in a specific set.  For instance:

4000,5000,5500-5560,7244

Is it possible to build this into a mysql query, or do I have to manually build the query:

```
 Select * from table where x=4000 or x=5000 or x between 5500 and 5560 or x=7244
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes its possible to build this query but u need some `()`

instead try this

```
   Select * from table where x in (4000,5000,7244 ) or x between 5500 and 5560
```

Comment: would it be faster to just convert the ranges to discrete values and put them in the set (4000,5000,7244,5500,5501...5560)?

Comment: it little better and shorter and will not conflict if you have some more of `AND` and `OR` . about speed i didnt check it .

Comment: here they talk about performance and speed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926433/mysql-performance-in-clause-vs-equals-for-a-single-value

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this would be the best query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE x IN (4000, 5000, 7244) OR (x >= 5500 AND x <= 5560);
```