# Single value for "IN" query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance

```
SELECT * FROM table_master WHERE column_id = 123
SELECT * FROM table_master WHERE column_id IN(456)
```

MSSQL execute above queries as follow.

```
SELECT * FROM table_master WHERE column_id = 123
SELECT * FROM table_master WHERE column_id = 456
```

By checking execution plan in MSSQL it looks similar to me for time difference.

But When I execute above queries there is bit time difference in MySQL.

```
SELECT * FROM table_master WHERE column_id = 123 -- 0.000 sec / 0.000 sec
SELECT * FROM table_master WHERE column_id IN(456) -- 0.016 sec / 0.000 sec
```

So what you guys suggesting for the MySQL? `=` and `IN` internally works same in `MySQL`? or I should use `=` in case of single value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926433/mysql-performance-in-clause-vs-equals-for-a-single-value

Comment: For such small time values a single execution is meaningless. Did you execute both multiple (say 1000) times in a loop? Did you also make sure you used the same values (not 123 and then 456) for both tests?

Comment: What if we have multiple users working at the same time?

Comment: @VickyThakor which is why they asked the question.

Comment: I did few test and came to conclusion that It doesn't matter and the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926433/mysql-performance-in-clause-vs-equals-for-a-single-value supports that.