# MySql IN vs = performance when looking for only a single value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a situation where most times I would be looking for a single value in a field, but sometimes I may be looking for multiple values; because of that I know I could just use `IN`, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_field IN ('3');
```

However, I was wondering if it would be worth it to check to see how many values we are going to be looking for so I could change it to a `=`, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_field=3;
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926433/mysql-performance-in-clause-vs-equals-for-a-single-value) but it wasn't really clear on if there are any performance differences on the *MySQL side*.

So my question is, should I bother to check how many values I will be looking for or just use `IN` for all queries? Is there any performance difference?

Comment: No difference, same execution. (However, '3' and 3 are two different things...)

Comment: How is _"there is no difference between the MySQL statements, and the MySQL optimiser will transform the IN to the = when IN is just one element. Don't bother"_ not _really clear_?

Comment: @TimSchmelter If you read the comments you will understand why it's not clear.

Comment: @Brett: good point. It's a duplicate anyway.