# Eloquent Eager Loading Query - IN vs WHERE

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've turned on the Query Log from Eloquent and was quite surprised what the ORM was doing in the background, especially in Eager Loading.

Let me explain:

```
class User extends Model{

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_user';

    public function child(){

        return $this->hasOne('Models\Child','id_user');
    }
}
```

Then somewhere I'm using it like this:

> User::with('child')->find(1);

The query in the Background should've been an simple **WHERE** using the **EQUAL ( = )** operator, because the Relationship is hasOne.

But looking up at the Query Logger this operation above returns:
**( Forget about the User's Query, that one is "right" )**

```
{
    "query": "select * from `childs` where `childs`.`id_user` in (?)",
    "bindings": [
        106
    ],
    "time": 0.36
}
```

The Query builded by the Eloquent is using the operator **IN** instead of **EQUAL ( = )** and this does not make sense at all unless they are equal in MySQL.

**Example:**

```
{
    "query": "select * from `childs` where `childs`.`id_user` = ?",
    "bindings": [
        106
    ],
    "time": 0.36
}
```

My question is: Can this Query be optimized ? Is this query slower than using **EQUAL ( = )** ?

Is Eloquent doing this or I doing something wrong with the Relationship ?

Comment: MySQL optimize IN (with single value) and = (EQUAL) in the same way, so it can not be optimized more. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926433/mysql-performance-in-clause-vs-equals-for-a-single-value

Comment: You can "optimize" more using cache.

Comment: Put as an answer so I can give you the correct one.