# MySQL using IN()

Tags: mysql

IN() is usually applied like this:

```
SELECT eid FROM comments WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Would this generate an error or is it just syntactically bad?

```
SELECT eid FROM comments WHERE id IN (6)
```

Comment: No, because you have `id IN (6)`, in that case it will just behave as if you wrote ` `WHERE id=6`

Comment: i posted a answer that proves @KebabProgrammer 's comment.

Answer (score 2):

It will work as expected. Most probably under the hood it will be optimised as `WHERE id = 6` anyway.

Comment: The timing tho XD

Comment: indeed it will be optimized under the hood, ive posted a answer that proves that..

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't generate error, it will work correctly,

because the point of `IN` clause - is to check whether value exists in defined list.

In your case this list contains only one value (6).

Answer (score 1):

No it will not error, the MySQL optimizer is smart in that because it knows `id IN (6)` is equal to `id = 6` and will handle it like that.

`SELECT eid FROM comments WHERE id IN (6)`

Will be rewritten/handled after optimizing as

`/* select#1 */ select test.comments.eid AS eid from test.comments where (
test.comments.id = 6)`

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oRjpwVQBYXBHDrwMZkzwyB/6)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL `IN()` function finds a match in the given arguments.

**Syntax:**

```
expr IN (value,...)
```

> The function returns 1 if expr is equal to any of the values in the IN
>   list, otherwise, returns 0. If all values are constants, they are
>   evaluated according to the type of expr and sorted. The search for the
>   item then is done using a binary search. This means IN is very quick
>   if the IN value list consists entirely of constants. Otherwise, type
>   conversion takes place according to the rules.

**For your case**, If you are conscious about the performance of `IN()` with one element vs `=`, actually there is no significant difference between the MySQL statements, and the MySQL optimizer will transform the `IN` to the `=` when IN is just one element.

Something like-

```
SELECT eid FROM comments WHERE id IN (6)
```

**to**

```
SELECT eid FROM comments WHERE id  = 6
```

It will arise performance issue if it contains multiple elements inside the `IN()`. You can try with `EXPLAIN` to see the difference. See [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31754630/1138192)

Comment: A large `IN()` or `OR` list can be optimized with a `UNION ALL` query.. i believe Oracle optimizer does this `IN()` and `OR` conversion to a `UNION ALL` query automatic if the id column is indexed.